# Chinese encoding in python OpenCV(cv2) putText method

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

For some reason, I need to put Chinese text in an cropped image. I have used the method "putText" in cv2 to achieve the goal.

Here is the code I use:

```
cv2.putText(crop_img, u'中文字串'.encode('utf-8'), (200, 200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3.0, textColor, thickness=4)
```

However, all the characters shown in the image became "?". How do I solve the problem? Does cv2 support Chinese encoding?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that OpenCV only has the Hershey font, which does not include Chinese characters.
So you need something else.
There is an [OpenCV extension library](https://code.google.com/p/opencv-extension-library/)  that appears to address the issue.

The program at http://opencv-extension-library.googlecode.com/svn/doc/r263/classCvxText.html#2b5076328cd67ddd5a4eecc8e00cba3e certainly looks like it is trying to load a font and draw characters in an image.

Comment: both of the above links are broken, if anyone find some alternative and comment it here. that will be helpful.